# name lookup of `a' changed for new ISO `for' scoping

Tags: c++, for-loop

I am trying to troubleshoot this error I get in c++. I've looked at similar questions on StackOverflow, but I can't seem to find the error for my particular solution. I have no idea why it doesn't work, nested for loops work fine this way from my knowledge. Let me know if you have a solution.

NOTE: This is just a code snippet. All variables are defined above. **I get the error on line 7.**

Here is the exact error message:

```
50 C:\Users\ryang\Desktop\check install\Untitled1.cpp name lookup of `a' changed for new ISO `for' scoping
```

Code:

```
for(int a = 0; a < 500; a ++)
    assets[a][0] = temp + temp2;
    for(int b = 1; b < 6; b ++)
    {
          userAssets >> temp >> temp2;
          if(temp == "CorporateIT")
                  assets[a][b] = temp2;
          else
          {
              numWorkstations[a] = b;
              break;
          }
    }   
}
```

Comment: Paste the exact error message into your question.

Comment: Please clarify "it doesn't work".  Provide, in your question, the expected result, the actual result and any relevant input data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you forgot the open brace (`{`) after the first `for` loop.

Answer (score 3):

When you place a variable in a for loop it is defined only inside that for loop. So when you have:

```
for(int a = 0; a < 500; a ++)
    assets[a][0] = temp + temp2;
```

The for loop ends at the semicolon here and as such the variable `a` is now not in scope.

What you need is your `for` loop to be enclosed with braces to avoid this. I'd suggest always using braces around for loops for this reason, my companies coding standards explicitly demand this to avoid running into the exact problem you encountered here.

Comment: Why does that occur exactly? I thought that the for loop contains everything within {}. Am I not able to nest for loops within eachother? What is a possible workaround

Comment: I feel like an idiot. All I did was forget the opening brace. Thanks!

Comment: Good catch on the ';'.  I was fooled by the indentation.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I was too at first, which is exactly why many coding standards don't allow this type of for loop, it's hard to spot at a glance.